# PHP 8.0 "Segmentation fault" when using characters with accent (ex: é, à, ...) in readline() string

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, character, readline, diacritics

readline() understands a string with normal characters, but once I write an accented character (é, â, ...) inside the string, I get an error: "Segmentation fault".

Example:

```
$age = (int)readline("âge : ");
```

I tried:

- removing VS Code extensions
- single-quoted string

I would greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: On which OS Is your PHP running? Which version? Was it compiled by you? Was it compiled with any uncommon libraries? Do you have any uncommon extensions enabled?

Comment: It's PHP 8.0.5 running on WSL Ubuntu. No library was used, and I got the same issue with the extensions removed (besides "Remote - WSL" because it's required).

Comment: It's a long shot but have you tried to disable `opcache`? (set `opcache.enable=0` after `[opcache]` in the `php.ini`)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still got the same problem. Should I try downgrading to PHP 7.4?

Comment: Well, downgrade might help. But it's hard to say for sure without knowing what the actual underlying problem is. For example, it could also be an issue with WSL itself. Personally I'm using PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 20.04 successfully. I've never tried WSL.

Comment: (anyway if you eventually solve it then I will be happy to know how)

Comment: Problem solved! I downgraded to PHP 7.4, and it works. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that readline doesnt accept accent characters, for any reason, so the solution was to remove the prompt from it:

```php
<php

print('Âge: ');
$age = (int) readline();
```

it has the same results, a text with a prompt message and the input cursor;

Answer (score -1):

I downgraded my PHP version to 7.4, and it works.

Here's a helpful article to do so: https://wpamitkumar.com/how-to-downgrade-php-80-to-74-ubuntu/